# SSL Certificate error in Apache 2.4

Tags: linux, ssl, apache-2.4, openssl

I am running two websites on Apache 2.4 webserver. It is configured as NameBaseVhost and both have their own wildcard ssl certificate (*.site1.com and *.site2.com) issued by Godaddy. 
Every thing is working fine. When I access websites through it's subdomain www.site1.com and www.site2.com it works fine. Apache has a Rewrite rule to redirect http to https so both the websites are redirecting perfectly.

Now the Problem is when I redirect root domain to www, for site2.com it gives me error.

```
Error code: ssl_error_bad_cert_domain

site2.com uses an invalid security certificate. 
The certificate is only valid for the following names: 
*.site1.com, site1.com
```

Httpd configuration of site1.com

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R]
# Redirect root domain to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.site1.com/$1 [R=301,L]

<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName www.site1.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site1/public/
SSLEngine On
SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/site1/site1.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/site1/site1.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/site1/gd_site1.crt
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000;
</VirtualHost>
```

Httpd Configuration for site2.com

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R]
# Redirect root domain to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site2\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.site2.com/$1 [R=301,L]

<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName www.site2.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site2/public/
SSLEngine On
SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/site2/site2.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/site2/site2.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/site2/gd_site2.crt
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000;
</VirtualHost>
```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: What happens if you put a serveralias site2.com in the site2 vhost ?

Comment: I have only a vague feeling which might be completely wrong but I'll still share it: your first rewrite rule which redirects from HTTP to HTTPS is okay but think what happens when the client reconnects using HTTPS -- *before* the SSL handshake completes, there's simply no HTTP host available because it's communicated via the HTTP headers by the client, and that happens over the *already established* SSL tunnel. Hence I'd say you should put your final rewriting inside corresponding virtual host blocks, like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8759906/720999) suggests.

Comment: Also note that name-based virtual hosting with HTTPS works only if both the server and the client use a special extension to TLS called "SNI", and using it requires at least TLSv1. Supposedly it *is* your case, but reading [the docs](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHostsWithSNI) could explain where my vague feeling came from.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is the use of `<VirtualHost *:443>` in the VHost.  Use the specific IP Addresses of the websites, otherwise all SSL traffic will be routed through the first VHost entry.